# How to make this liquid/fluid/melt effect?

Tags: shaders, fluid-simulation, displacement, distort

I was wondering if you guys can help me figure out how to recreate this kind of effect (see the attached image). I’ve tried with the fluid simulator (mantaflow) but couldn’t make it work as well as the dynamic paint modifier (waves).

The artist has stated that he used the "...Refraction BSDF as a base" for the shading.

[image: 2]
[image: 3]
Images are part of Yan Cook’s work ["SUBATOMIC REFRACTION #2"](https://www.behance.net/gallery/90806015/Subatomic-Refraction-2)

Thank you!